# How to using scheme with recursion to insert a number to a sorted number, and the merged numbers are still sorted?((insert 1245 3)->12345)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, recursion, scheme, racket

How to using scheme with recursion to insert a number to a sorted number? I did an iteration as below when the number needs to insert is larger than the rest digit stop and (rest * 10^(count+1))+(insert-n * 10^count)+ result-so-far. Otherwise, (iter (quotient rest 10) (+ count 1) insert-n (+ (* (modulo rest 10) (expt 10 count)) result-so-far))))). I try many times in recursion but not work. Looks like a dynamic problem is using recursion. Did anyone have any idea about it?

```
(define (insert-number sorted-num insert-n)
        (define (iter rest count insert-n result-so-far)
                 (cond ((>= insert-n (modulo rest 10))
                        (+ (* rest (expt 10 (+ count 1)))
                           (* insert-n (expt 10 count))
                           result-so-far))
                       (else (iter (quotient rest 10)
                                   (+ count 1)
                                   insert-n
                                   (+ (* (modulo rest 10) (expt 10 count)) result-so-far)))))

  
 (iter sorted-num 0 insert-n 0)
  )
```

Comment: What on earth is a sorted number, and what does it mean to insert a number into one?

Comment: @amalloy The sorted number is 1245, and I want to insert a number in the sorted number,  and after the merge, the number still is a stored number like,  3 is inserted into 1245 =12345

Comment: You wanted to insert a "digit" to a number with all digits in sorted order so that the resulting number also has sorted digits? Use binary search. If you wanted to actually merge two numbers, look at a similar problem called "merge two sorted arrays".

Comment: @prakasht they are difference. “Merge two sorted arrays” using arrays, and easy to call each position. But this problem just two number, need to know which digit need to move and which digit need to stay and add the number in the tail

Comment: Perhaps converting the number into a string for the insert then back into an integer would help to illuminate the solution?

Comment: @Lazerbeak12345 But the problem need to only use number... It makes me uncomfortable

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible a more clever way, but this is what I could write down in 2 minutes:

```
(define (insert-digit sorted-num digit)
  (let loop ((snl sorted-num) (snr 0) (place 1))
    (let ((r (remainder snl 10)))
      (if (> r digit)
          (loop (quotient snl 10)
                (+ snr (* place r))
                (* place 10))
          (+ (* snl place 10)
             (* digit place)
             snr)))))
```

How it works is that if you call it `(insert-digit 123456 3)` it will divide the number in left hand side and right hand side and when it has come to `123` and `456` then `r` will not be greater than `d` and thus it uses multiplications to put `snl`, `d`, and `snr` to one number `123456`.